# Modify a .cs file in pre-compile event

Tags: c#

I try to modify a .cs class with an external program in the pre-compile-event.

unfortunately the changes in the file are not included in the current compile. What can i do to get the changes from the external program into the compile?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio, make a new project in your solution called "PreBuild" or something like that.  Use project dependencies to make sure that your C# project builds after the PreBuild project, then put the command that modifies your .cs class as a build event of PreBuild.

Comment: Yes! The project dependencies did it! Thank you!